# получить данные из json (локальный файл)

Tags: javascript

**Пишу небольшое приложение в реакт. Добавил метод fetch в функциональный компонент.**

```
fetch('src/data/data-socials.json')
        .then(res => {
            if(!res.ok){
                throw new Error("HTTP error " + res.status);
            }
            return res.json()
        }).then(data => console.log(data)).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

**файл data-socials.json**

````
{
  "instagramLink" :{
  "classOfSocial": "social instagram",
   "href" :"https://www.instagram.com",
  "classFaFa"   :"fa fa-instagram fa-2x"
},

  "vkLink" :{
    "classOfSocial": "social vk",
    "href" :"https://www.instagram.com",
    "classFaFa"   :"fa fa-vk fa-2x"
  },

  "linledOnLinl" :{
    "classOfSocial": "social linkedin",
    "href" :"https://www.linkedin.com/in",
    "classFaFa"   :"fa fa-linkedin fa-2x"
  }
}
**``` Ожидаю 3 обЪекта, а получаю ошибку JSON.parse:**
````

Answer (score 1):

Локальный файл нельзя получить через `fetch`.

Если речь идёт о получении серверного файла с сайта, то следует его поместить в какое-то место, где раздающий сервер (а через него и клиент) сможет до него добраться. И вряд ли это будет папка с исходниками. К тому же, ты используешь относительный путь, который (в текущем виде) предполагает, что страница находится рядом с папкой `src`.

Если же речь идёт о node.js и доступе к файлу на самом сервере, то с json'ом отлично работает обычный require:

```
var data = require('./src/data/data-socials.json')
```

впрочем, он однократно загрузит файл и будет в последующем отдавать именноэту версию.

Если требуется считывать актуальную версию файла, стоит читать его самому при помощи `fs.readFile`, по необходимости удалять BOM, а затем отдавать строку в `JSON.parse`.